# Linq to SQL does not SUM all rows

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq to SQL query:

```
Logs
.GroupBy(g => new { g.DateStamp.Date, g.Result, g.ConversionCost} )
.Select(s => new {Date = s.Key.Date, s.Key.Result, Cost = s.Sum(sum=>sum.ConversionCost), Count = s.Count()})
.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Date)
```

And it does not give the desired result. The s.Sum(sum=>sum.ConversionCost) does not sum all numbers from g.ConversionCost group.

[image]

The above image displays the results, however the Date field contains duplicates when GroupedBy g.ConversionCost.

If I remove g.ConversionCost from grouping and SUM from Select

```
Logs
.GroupBy(g => new { g.DateStamp.Date, g.Result} )
.Select(s => new {Date = s.Key.Date, s.Key.Result, Count = s.Count()})
.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Date)
```

I get the correct result

[image]

g.ConversionCost field is numeric int32 values NotNull and I do not understand why grouping and SUM'ing on it I get duplicate values in my final result. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the grouping on `ConversionCost` and keeping the SUM?

Comment: @Rafalon It solves the problem! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I **remove `g.ConversionCost` from grouping** and SUM from Select I get correct result

Removing `g.ConversionCost` from grouping is exactly what makes it work as expected, removing the SUM isn't.

The problem you had is that you would have groups of results with say:

```
Date = 8/21/2018
Result = true
ConversionCost = 1205 // whatever
Count = 201 // number of rows with this date, this result AND this ConversionCost

Date = 8/21/2018
Result = true
ConversionCost = 1206 // another conversion cost
Count = 10
```

SUM'ing those by `ConversionCost` would only "*convert*" this group to:

```
Date = 8/21/2018
Result = true
Cost = 242205 // = 1205*201

Date = 8/21/2018
Result = true
Cost = 12060 // = 1206*10
```